# How to label x axes at critical points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a graph made with matplotlib which should be labeled at extrema points (horizontal axes). As it has many values on x axes, it is not readable: [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHayH.png)
Thus I have to use  
 `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::len(x)//20])`
 So, it splits the x axes into several equal parts: [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ehSc.png) 
 As it can be seen, this approach skips many important values.

Comment: What's your definition of "extrema points"?

Comment: I want to label the horizontal axes at points at which the function either has local minimum or local maximum.

Comment: Hmm, I can imagine it not being extremely readable. The density of local minima and maxima in your data is quite big. Maybe you can filter your data and then look for minima and maxima but the result will strongly depend on the data you are working on. If you can share a sample it would be easier to help

Comment: Pasted data here https://pastebin.com/riiVmZ7U

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357209/mplcursors-show-and-highlight-coordinates-of-nearby-local-extreme/60358143#60358143) is an example which shows the local extremes while hovering (or clicking) with the mouse.