# How to increase the number of digits of x and y coordinates shown?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mplcursors

Using the `%matplotlib notebook` in matplotlib we get the plot

[image: plot]

**How to increase the number of digits after the decimal point in the `x` and `y` coordinates, displayed after passing my mouse over the graph?**

And thank you.

Comment: With [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io) you can easily create your own hover annotations, where you control the number of digits and any extra information.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC!
Is there another way to increase the digits without installing, because I'm not using jupyter-notebook on my local machine, in the "cloud" rather :)

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors/tree/master/lib/mplcursors) is only a few files. You could copy them directly to your "cloud".

Comment: Ok @JohanC I did it, where can I add digits on the `x` and `y` coordinates :)

Comment: Did the `mplcursors.cursor()` have some parameters to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The `hover` option is set, so the functionality is called while hovering (instead of only when clicking).

Standard a yellow annotation window is shown, of which you can update the text. You can disable this annotation if you only want to display something in the status bar.

The code below shows the cursor coordinates when hovering close to the curve. The default cursor display is disabled.

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357209/mplcursors-show-and-highlight-coordinates-of-nearby-local-extreme/60358143#60358143) shows an example how mplcursors can identify a local maximum.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np

def show_annotation(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(f'{sel.annotation.xy[0]:.12f};{sel.annotation.xy[1]:.12f}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",
                       lambda event: fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(""))
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", show_annotation)
```

PS: To just use the standard annotation, you can write `show_annotation` as follows:

```
def show_annotation(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_text(f'x:{sel.annotation.xy[0]:.12f}\ny:{sel.annotation.xy[1]:.12f}')
```

Mplcursors seems not to be showing annotations or status bar updates after zooming in while in hovering mode. Setting `hover=False` (the default mode) would result in the same behavior, but only after a click (or double click when zoomed).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np

def show_annotation(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(f'{sel.annotation.xy[0]:.12f};{sel.annotation.xy[1]:.12f}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=False)
cursor.connect("add", show_annotation)
plt.show()
```

To always see the decimals, independent of being near a curve, you could try the following (without mplcursors):

```py
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",
                        lambda event: fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(f"{event.xdata:.12f};{event.ydata:.12f}"))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @JohanC I used the `%matplotlib notebook` with the code above, and then I zoomed on a point on the graph but I no longer have the number of digits increased. Do you have another way to zoom on a point without losing the digits added?
And thank you.

Comment: Actually, with just clicking on the square button that corresponds to the zoom, after nothing zoomed I notice that the added digits is no longer there, and that happens for both codes (the original and the edited ones).
And sorry for being annoying.

Comment: Clicking on the zoom button puts you in zoom-mode. Then zoom mode takes over the status bar.  From then on you need to double click to see the extended precision.

Comment: Thank you! 
Another question if you don't mind; I noticed that this code adds this extended precision if my mouse is on the line of the graph, otherwise it returns to the imprecise coordinates. is this code restricted to this behavior or there is a way to overcome it?
And thank for being patient with me :)

Comment: After some experimenting, I came up with a solution without mplcursors. Does it work for you?

Comment: Awesome! yes, that works, thank you so much. My greeting Mr.JohanC